# Restricting SPARQL result pairs to non-reflexive pairs

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web

Assume data like this:

```
<event1> member <A>
<event1> member <B>
<event1> member <C>
<event2> member <D>
<event2> member <E>
```

I am looking for pairs  that are connected via the same membership event. i.e. here:

```
A B
A C
B C
D E
```

and the reversed order may or may not be included (both fine for my use-case).
owever, a query like this

```
select distinct ?x ?y 
  where {?m member ?x. ?m member ?y}
```

will also include the trivial pairs like `A A` or `B B`.

How can I restrict results to those with different ?x and ?y?
I tried adding `?x != ?y` as another triple in the where clause and via FILTER but neither seems to work

Comment: I wouldn't expect `?x != ?y` to work in a triple pattern, since it's not a triple.  Can you show the case using `FILTER` that didn't work, though?  `FILTER( ?x != ?y )` should work, depending on the type of `?x` and `?y`.  `FILTER( !sameTerm( ?x, ?y ))` would be a little bit more general, if the first is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Although you posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17195213/1281433) that works for you, I'll point out that the syntax that you had a problem with doesn't seem to be SPARQL issue, but with the store/SPARQL engine that you used.  Using Jena's ARQ, I can load the following `data.n3` and execute the following `query.sparql` and get the results that you describe:

`data.n3`:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/> .

:event1 :member :a .
:event1 :member :a .
:event1 :member :b .
:event2 :member :c .
:event2 :member :d .
```

`query.sparql`:

```
PREFIX : <http://example.org/>

SELECT ?x ?y WHERE {
  ?event :member ?x, ?y .
  FILTER( ?x != ?y )
}
```

Here are the results when run using Jena's command line tools:

```
$ arq  --query query.sparql --data data.n3 
-----------
| x  | y  |
===========
| :d | :c |
| :c | :d |
| :b | :a |
| :a | :b |
-----------
```

Comment: i was able to reproduce the same behavior with your example. it seems rdf3x does not like != (while ARQ does). for rdf3x, !(?x = ?y) does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
select distinct ?x ?y 
   where {?m member ?x. ?m member ?y. filter(!(?x = ?y))}
```

This did the trick for me, while `filter(?x != ?y)` led to an empty result. 
I am not sure if this is really SPARQL related or a mssing feature in rdf3x, the triple store I used

Comment: What sort of values are `?x` and `?y` here?  Depending on that, you might want to consider [`sameTerm`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-sameTerm), with which you can do `FILTER( !sameTerm(?x,?y) )`.